# Database reset everything on a real android device

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I tried to figure out what's wrong with my code, I copied exactly the same code online and carefully replace it with my own variable, and it's still not working, I scratched head.. This morning I start to realise my mistake! because the database exist in my real android device, so I cannot simply modify the table column and value! nothing wrong with my code actually!

But I also don't want to uninstall and relaunch my app, it's killing me, any solution?

Comment: You can clear the data without uninstalling.

Comment: explain more? I don't understand..

Comment: Lol, you got the steps on your answer. Sorry I was not around to answer sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your device go to Setting > apps > your app...  Click Clear data.  This will delete your database.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications.
2. Look for your application and click it
3. Click on clear data.